# React-native, ios, render shadow only

Tags: ios, react-native, shadow

I'm trying to create a white, circular shadow in IOS, but ONLY the shadow.  When placing shadow props on a View no backgroundColor or transparent backgroundColor the shadow will pass to the first child element with dimensions.  Is it possible to utilize IOS shadow props to create a nice circular glow effect?

This is what I'm looking for:

[image]

This was done using react-native-shadow, but is for Android only.  Hoping to achieve a similar effect with IOS shadow props.

Currently on IOS I have this:

[image]

there really is a shadow, but it's very faint

Here's what I'm doing on the IOS side right now:

```
<View style={[styles.iconAndTextContainer, styles.iosIconShadow]}>
  // shadow is placed on this icon element which has a height and width
  {icon}
  <ThemedText color={iconColor}>{label}</ThemedText>
</View>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    iconAndTextContainer: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    iosIconShadow: {
        shadowColor: '#fff',
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 1,
        shadowRadius: 10,
    },
});
```

ideally I'd like to do this:

```
<View style={styles.iconAndTextContainer}>
  // have an absolute positioned View right in the middle that is transparent, but creates a white shadow to create that 'glow' effect
  <View style={[styles.iosIconShadow, {position: 'absolute'}]} />
  {icon}
  <ThemedText color={iconColor}>{label}</ThemedText>
</View>
```

Comment: Is it the same to enlarge the size of the icon area?

Comment: I want the icon to stay the same size though.  If i put a view around it with height and width, it passes the shadow to the first element with a background that isn't transparent which is the icon itself again.

Comment: try this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

Comment: i needed to produce a radial gradient... ended up using [react-native-shadow](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow) for android and ios